# How to use "in comparison" in this sentence

Tags: comparisons

How can I use "*in comparison*" in the following sentence, without changing its context or meaning?

> Computers-based communication is extremely fast,  telephone services are slow

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will note, we can best help you if *you* identify where you think it should go and why it confuses you, and explain what you are trying to express. If this is homework, please let us know as well (and if so, alert your instructor that the sentence has a [comma splice](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/34/). Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may also interest you.

Answer (score 2):

You could rearrange the sentence thus:

- *In comparison to* extremely fast computer-based communications, telephone services are slow.

then simplify it:

- *Compared to* extremely fast computer-based communications, telephone services are slow.

BTW, the original sentence should use a semicolon, not a comma.  Also, it's lacking a period.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> Computer-based communication is extremely fast, *while in comparison to* telephone services are slow.

Here, I'm using *while* as a conjunction between the two clauses.  You could also use *though*.  Other acceptable, though less preferred, conjunctions would be *but* or *and*.

Then, I use *in comparison* to specifically guide the reader to compare telephone services to computer-based communication.  We could omit the *in comparison* and broadly retain the same meaning, but it wouldn't illicit the explicit comparison.

Also, for the record, *Computers-based communication is extremely fast, telephone services are slow.* is not a grammatically correct sentence:  the comma is inappropriately connecting these two clauses.  A semicolon would be the preferred punctuation mark.